# python : empty output is printing while reading the web browser output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have set of URL links in my file and i need to open every link and fetch the output and i need to store that in a file. But if i tried to print output empty lines are coming.
Please find the code below and help me on this

```
import urllib2

import webbrowser

with open('C:\\Users\\home\\Desktop\\11.txt','r') as fp:
    for line in fp:

        password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
        top_level_url = "https://facebook.com"
        password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, "appsdev", "--omitted--")
        handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
        r=opener.open(top_level_url)
        r.read()
        print r.read()
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Done with my editing

Comment: Looks like that you don't use the `line` for anything. In general, what you try to do is to scrape a user's FB page with a bot. That's a scenario what companies like FB try to prevent because it is suspicious activity. You may run into some prevention mechanisms. Interesting code BTW.

Comment: Thank u for pointing me :) . In general i used FB to post in Stack overflow but i need to replace with some other links :D  @Csaba Toth

Answer (score 0):

If the code you posted is correct and the 2nd `r.read()` isn't a typo, then it's because you have two reads.

On file-like objects (like the return value from `opener.open()`), calling `read()` will return the entire contents and set the current position to the end of the file.  Subsequent calls to `read()` will return empty strings, since the cursor is already at the end of the file.

In your code

```
r.read()  # This returns the entire contents
print r.read()  # Empty string
```

Just get rid of the first `r.read()`.

Comment: I want to delete my read() command? How to over come this issue?

Comment: But the main problem i am facing here is i wanted to write that output in to file (i.e. If i open 1st link in an input file and i wanted to write the corresponding output to output file)

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking.  You can write the output to a file just by opening another file and writing the results of `r.read()` to the file.

Comment: I wanted to write the output to a file , i added below code to write the file file_object = open("C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\10.txt","w")
print r.read().......................but empty file is saved after running it :(

Answer (score 0):

Before Writing into some other file , assign that content into any variable,

like ,

```
 out_data = r.read()
 new_file = open('file.txt','w')
 new_file.write(out_data)
 new_file.close()
```

thats it your scraped data will be be wrote into `file.txt`

Comment: I tried with above code, but still no luck :( Empty file is saved in the location @Mohideen ibn Mohammed

Comment: Its working, but i need my output in a organized way (like out put of 1st url in 1st line and so on......)

Comment: i got urd but ur example code not like that.. because your URL is not from parsed txt file instead you using hardcoded one.. you want to create separate txt file for each URL from , with open('C:\\Users\\home\\Desktop\\11.txt','r') as fp: 
    for line in fp:

Comment: oops! its my mistake . i want to fetch the url from my text file                     
Could you please help me on how to fetch it in repetitive manner

Comment: yes , but each url return large html tab right, so do u want to write it in a separate txt file for each url or u want same txt for all URL? it will make me easy to tell